# xdotool to tab to a button on a web page and use the mouse to disable a drop down menu option

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, xdotool, amazon-chime

I have a Bash script that open a Amazon chime meeting URL in firefox, uses XDOtool to enter a meetig participant name, and tab and mouse click functions. and next uses ffmpeg to stream the video and audio output of the Amazon chime meeting to an RTMP destination.

When this is streamed, the Amazon chime web app has "More" drop down Menu. Within the Menu it has a option to disable the self view. I want to add xdotool commands to disable this self view option from the more drop down menu on the amazon chime web app page.

the Amazon chime meeting URL is  - https://app.chime.aws/meetings/

Here is the Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
BROWSER_URL=${MEETING_URL}
SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080
SCREEN_RESOLUTION=${SCREEN_WIDTH}x${SCREEN_HEIGHT}
CAPTURE_SCREEN_RESOLUTION=1920x1080
COLOR_DEPTH=24
X_SERVER_NUM=2
VIDEO_BITRATE=6000
VIDEO_FRAMERATE=30
VIDEO_GOP=$((VIDEO_FRAMERATE * 2))
AUDIO_BITRATE=160k
AUDIO_SAMPLERATE=44100
AUDIO_CHANNELS=2

# Start PulseAudio server so Firefox will have somewhere to which to send audio
pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1
pacmd load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=v1  # Load a virtual sink as `v1`
pacmd set-default-sink v1  # Set the `v1` as the default sink device
pacmd set-default-source v1.monitor  # Set the monitor of the v1 sink to be the default source

# Start X11 virtual framebuffer so Firefox will have somewhere to draw
Xvfb :${X_SERVER_NUM} -ac -screen 0 ${SCREEN_RESOLUTION}x${COLOR_DEPTH} > /dev/null 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:${X_SERVER_NUM}.0
sleep 0.5  # Ensure this has started before moving on

# Create a new Firefox profile for capturing preferences for this
firefox --no-remote --new-instance --createprofile "foo4 /tmp/foo4"

# Install the OpenH264 plugin for Firefox
mkdir -p /tmp/foo4/gmp-gmpopenh264/1.8.1.1/
pushd /tmp/foo4/gmp-gmpopenh264/1.8.1.1 >& /dev/null
curl -s -O http://ciscobinary.openh264.org/openh264-linux64-2e1774ab6dc6c43debb0b5b628bdf122a391d521.zip
unzip openh264-linux64-2e1774ab6dc6c43debb0b5b628bdf122a391d521.zip
rm -f openh264-linux64-2e1774ab6dc6c43debb0b5b628bdf122a391d521.zip
popd >& /dev/null

# Set the Firefox preferences to enable automatic media playing with no user
# interaction and the use of the OpenH264 plugin.
cat <<EOF >> /tmp/foo4/prefs.js
user_pref("media.autoplay.default", 0);
user_pref("media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed", false);
user_pref("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.abi", "x86_64-gcc3");
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate", 1571534329);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version", "1.8.1.1");
user_pref("doh-rollout.doorhanger-shown", true);
EOF

# Start Firefox browser and point it at the URL we want to capture
#
# NB: The `--width` and `--height` arguments have to be very early in the
# argument list or else only a white screen will result in the capture for some
# reason.
firefox \
  -P foo4 \
  --width ${SCREEN_WIDTH} \
  --height ${SCREEN_HEIGHT} \
  --new-instance \
  --first-startup \
  --foreground \
  --kiosk \
  --ssb \
  "${BROWSER_URL}" \
  &
sleep 10  # Ensure this has started before moving on, waiting for loading the Chime web app
xdotool key Return #Select yes for the pop-up window of "Would you like to open this link with Chime app?"
sleep 3
xdotool key Escape #Close the pop-up window
sleep 3
xdotool type Livestream #Type "Livestream" on the name input field
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab #Move to "join the meeting" button
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Click "join the meeting" button
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Close the pop-up window once again
sleep 3
xdotool key Escape #Close the pop-up window once again
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Click "Use system audio" setting
sleep 3
xdotool key Escape #Close warning message
sleep 3
xdotool mousemove 1 1 click 1  # Move mouse out of the way so it doesn't trigger the "pause" overlay on the video tile  

# Start ffmpeg to transcode the capture from the X11 framebuffer and the
# PulseAudio virtual sound device we created earlier and send that to the RTMP
# endpoint in H.264/AAC format using a FLV container format.
#
# NB: These arguments have a very specific order. Seemingly inocuous changes in
# argument order can have pretty drastic effects, so be careful when
# adding/removing/reordering arguments here.
ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -nostdin \
  -s ${CAPTURE_SCREEN_RESOLUTION} \
  -r ${VIDEO_FRAMERATE} \
  -draw_mouse 0 \
  -f x11grab \
    -i ${DISPLAY} \
  -f pulse \
    -ac 2 \
    -i default \
    -vf "crop=1600:980:0:1080" \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset slow \
    -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
  -filter_complex "aresample=async=1000:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=1" \
  -async 1 \
  -c:a aac \
    -b:a ${AUDIO_BITRATE} \
    -ac ${AUDIO_CHANNELS} \
    -ar ${AUDIO_SAMPLERATE} \
  -f flv ${RTMP_URL}``
```

what i have tried so far in in the bash script

Comment: That looks good, just use `xdotool getmouselocation` for the screen locations to `xdotool` the other menu.

Comment: thanks i added the following to try and make it more rubust: